# Incorrect package imports

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-gradle-plugin, package

I am trying with Automated UI testing, so followed [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html), the strange thing i observed that the google code snippet shows different package imports then mine.

Like for the UiObject class, google imported this

```
android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject
```

However, in my code its

```
com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject
```

Which results some unidentified method.I have no idea, what i am doing wrong, please help me.

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.automatinguitestingsample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
    compile files('libs/uiautomator.jar')
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `compile files('libs/uiautomator.jar')`, remove that JAR file from `libs/` (so it does not get picked up by the `compile fileTree(...)` stuff), then switch over to Google's imports (e.g., `android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject`).

Comment: @commonsware : by removing that jar from libs, all the methods become unidentified, no import option for any class

Comment: Make sure you are putting your test code in the `androidTest` sourceset. Your dependency for `com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18` is `androidTestCompile`, as it should be. However, that limits your testing code to be in `androidTest`, also as it should be. [Here is a sample project demonstrating the use of UiAutomator in Android Studio](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/UiAutomator), though I am using `2.0.0` rather than `2.1.1`.